# write dataframe to excel file at given path

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
```

This is working:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

but when I try:

```
out_path = "C:\Users\Bala\output\temp-excel.xlsx"
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path , engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

I'm getting error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\Bala Nadella\\output\temp-excel.xlsx'.
```

How can I create a file at a given path?

Comment: You should add the error you're getting. Does the directory C:\Users\Bala\output\ exist?

Comment: Yes. That is local directory of my box and it works for to_csv.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[String literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals)

Study the table in that link. You need to escape your '\' with '\\'. Partly, DOS is responsible for this mess in the world.

```
out_path = "C:\\Users\\Bala\\output\\temp-excel.xlsx"
```

Or

```
out_path = r"C:\Users\Bala\output\temp-excel.xlsx" # the `r` prefix means raw string
```

But best alternative is this:

```
out_path = "C:/Users/Bala/output/temp-excel.xlsx"
```

It will work on any platform.

---

Edited to remove the solution with `os.path.abspath`. After the comment below this answer, I read the documentation myself and realized that it has a different purpose. Although I have used it in the past to make my code dual OS friendly, because it neatly appends CWD to the path, and changes `/` to `\\` when moving from Debian to Windows and vice versa.

Comment: `os.path.abspath` is a nice function, but you have completely misrepresented what it does. It can't magically interpret literal backslashes in strings, and it is not at all what is needed here. Honestly, the **best** solution **is** to use forward slashes instead of backslashes (even in Windows). If you insist on using backslashes, you should be using *raw strings*.

Comment: You are right. Answer edited. I used to use it for situations, when I had both Windows and Ubuntu on my machine, and required the same code to run on files in my CWD. I found it quite handy, but it is not the solution to this question.

Comment: Good edit, now I feel comfortable upvoting this answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me somehow. I tried to wrap the entire thing in a function: `def excel_to_path(frame, path):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path , engine='xlsxwriter')
    frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    writer.save()` and to pass `df`and `"../foo/bar/myfile.xlsx"` any ideas?

Comment: @Rachel try replacing the relative path with absolute path. Also please use [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/). The doc shows [pandas implementation](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#io-excel-writer). It'll save your butt when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In a string the backslash is an escape character. It means that you're giving a special command, not a regular character. Eg. `"Hello\nWorld"` means, put a newline between `"Hello"` and `"World"`.

If you actually want to use a backslash as a character, type it as `"\\"`.

Or better yet, just use forward slashes!