# Write dataframe to path outside current directory with a function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, pandas, path, export-to-excel

I got a question that relates to (maybe is a duplicate of) this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884164/write-dataframe-to-excel-file-at-given-path).

I try to write a pandas dataframe to an Excel file (non-existing before) in a given path. Since I have to do it quite a few times, I try to wrap it in a function. Here is what I do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

def excel_to_path(frame, path):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path , engine='xlsxwriter')
    frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Output')
    writer.save()

excel_to_path(df, "../foo/bar/myfile.xlsx")
```

I get thrown the error `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../foo/bar/myfile.xlsx'`. How come and how can I fix it?

**EDIT** : It works as long the defined `path`is inside the current working directory. But I'd like to specify any given `path`instead. Ideas?

Comment: The code works on my pc

Comment: I just realized that it works as long `path` is inside the current directory - but not if it's outside. Any ideas?

Comment: Path in code example is `../foo/bar/myfile.xlsx`, path in error description is `../for/bar/myfile.xlsx`. `foo != for`; is that a typo in your question, or is it the underlying problem?

Comment: That was a typo! Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually get bitten by forgetting to create the directories. Perhaps the path `../foo/bar/` doesn't exist yet? Pandas will create the file for you, but not the parent directories.

To elaborate, I'm guessing that your setup looks like this:

```
.
└── src
    ├── foo
    │   └── bar
    └── your_script.py
```

with `src` being your working directory, so that `foo/bar` exists relative to you, but `../foo/bar` does not - yet!

So you should add the `foo/bar` directories one level up:

```
.
├── foo_should_go_here
│   └── bar_should_go_here
└── src
    ├── foo
    │   └── bar
    └── your_script.py
```