# Write DataFrame to several Excel Files based on changing cell value

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, for-loop

I got a DataFrame with which looks like this.

| Plant Location | Material Name | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Berlin | A-Material | Peter |
| London | B-Material | Peter |
| London | B-Material | James |

The table has about 1000 rows with different data and it is sorted for the Name. (all entries belonging to Peter, James, etc. following each other)

My goal is to iterate over the DataFrame, and split it into several Excel-Files, based on the column "Name".
I would then get seperate Excel file with all the copied data for each different "Name", like Peter, James, etc.

So far I only could program the following for loop which gives me back, if there is a change in the Name after finishing one column.

```
for row in range(len(df)):
    if df['Name'][row] == df['Namename'][row+1]:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("not true")
```

I think i would somehow need to include an to.Excel() command to get the data into specific files.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the unique names sequentially:

```
for name in df['Name'].unique():
    # Do something
```

Next, filter the DataFrame by the current name and save it:

```
for name in df['Name'].unique():
    df[df['Name'] == name].to_excel(name+'.xlsx') # Or another file name
```

Comment: In my solution, we first select all unique names (a list of names with no repetitions). Then, for each of the names in this list, we filter the DataFrame, and then we save it.

Comment: Thank you Vladislav!! How can I specify the direction where all the newly created Excel-Files will be saved to? (error message: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: 'FEP'). I tried with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884164/write-dataframe-to-excel-file-at-given-path but I'm failing to specify the directory for dynamic creation

Comment: I could at least specify one file path on my desktop and it created an Excel-File but without content. How to save to several Excel-Files depending on Name?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your desired directory structure?

Comment: The to_excel function saves a new file, if you specify a name in the filename, it will create several files. In your case, the selected folder does not exist, but you can create it yourself. If the folder names are also dynamic, use os.mkdir, and to_excel later

Comment: Also thanks for that hints. I found a full solution on Youtube which is almost the same as yours. For everyone interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWD2LSSuyjE